# Apple Maps consume too much memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory, mapkit, ios10

I need to implement in a view five mapViews of a concrete location (coordinates). I'm implementing the five mapViews in a UICollectionViewController (5 rows, one mapView for each row). The running application it consumes a lot of memory (more than 200mb).

I guess each map loads the whole world, that's a lot of jobs. But what I need to do it's only display the current coordinates I provide, not the whole world. Any idea or suggestion to make the mapViews lighter? Can I only show a map for a concrete region (coordinates) and a radius, without allowing to load the entire world?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the map view and not a memory leak of some sort? e.g. are you creating a new map view every time the cell reloads?

Comment: Do the maps need interaction? if not, you could potentially just create images of that are on the map and display the images.

Comment: Have you used the Allocations Tool to understand how your app is consuming memory? If so, post the appropriate output and also post your relevant code.

Comment: `MKMapShapshotter` is designed for precisely this use case, where you just need to show a fixed image for a given location. See [Creating a snapshot of a map](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW13) in the _Location and Maps Programming Guide._ Also demo'ed in WWDC 2013 [Putting Maps in Perspective](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/309/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapView is expected to take that much memory. MapView is not just plain view, there are a lot of things that goes into creation of mapView instance. For example images and data for location shown on mapView.

For your use case, I would strongly recommend using MKMapSnapshotter. Here is documentation link - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapSnapshotter_class/